# How can I rebase work on a feature branch after I've already merged it back

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

Working on a project with git, I have two feature branches, call them `dev-a` and `dev-b`, branched from my `develop` branch (which is branched from `master`).

I worked on `dev-a` for a bit, finished it, and merged it back into `develop`, did a little work on `develop`, and started on `dev-b`, worked for a bit, then found something that should have been done on `dev-a`, so I checkout `dev-a`, and fix it. My DAG now looks like this:

*commit hashes are obviously made up and not real hashes; they're just for reference*

```
*   008 - (dev-a) Fix problem on dev-a
|
| * 007 - (dev-b) Work on dev-b
| * 006 - Work on dev-b
| |
| * 005 - (develop) Work on develop
| * 004 - Work on develop
| * 003 - Merged dev-a
|/|
* | 002 - Work on dev-a
* | 001 - Work on dev-a
 \|
  * 000 - Work on develop
  |
```

What I want to do, though, is have that commit happen "before" the merge, so that I can rebase `develop` and `dev-b` on top of it, keeping everything neat and tidy:

```
  * 007 - (dev-b) Work on dev-b
  * 006 - Work on dev-b
  |
  * 005 - (develop) Work on develop
  * 004 - Work on develop
  * 003 - Merged dev-a
 /|
* | 008 - (dev-a) Fix problem on dev-a
* | 002 - Work on dev-a
* | 001 - Work on dev-a
 \|
  * 000 - Work on develop
  |
```

It's also important to note that the fix for `dev-a` won't conflict with any later commits - it's a fairly small change to a single file. All of the relevant commits are local and haven't been shared.

I'm fairly certain I can do this, as git is fairly flexible, but I don't know for sure if it's possible, how to do it, or whether it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all very straightforward, just do the merge again and rebase everything against it.

```
# make a branch of the 'develop' right before the merge
git checkout -b new-base 000 
# merge again
git merge dev-a

git checkout develop
# it moves all 'develop' commits made after the merge onto the new base.
git rebase new-base

git checkout dev-b
# moves all 'dev-b' commits onto the rebased 'develop'.
git rebase develop

# drop it, I don't think it has any value now.
git branch -d new-base
```

Comment: But when I `rebase new-base`, what happens with that merge commit (`003`)? Wouldn't I have *two* merge commits, then? One from merging `dev-a` from commit `008` and one from merging `dev-a` from commit `002`?

Comment: Alright, this works, with one exception, `git merge dev-a` needs to be `git merge --no-ff dev-a` otherwise it (at least in my case) does a fast-forward, turning it into linear history.

Comment: @AustinHyde Yes, the git is wise enough to figure out that the merge is done in the `new-base`, so it will throw out your first merge during rebase.